# Symfony2 Twig Conditional Template Name

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm looking for a way to check in my twig template if the `name of the template` contains a special word. If that is the case I want to proceed with assigning some stuff. Here is a general idea I have in mind.

```
{% if [sth like app.request.template_name or sth like that]  in `product` %}
 // Do some stuff
{% endif % }
```

Can you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating separate template files then you'll know the names and can hardcode the values:

template_1.html.twig:

```
{% set some_var = 1 %}
{% set another_var = 2 %}
```

template_2.html.twig:

```
{% set custom_var = 5 %}
```

---

Update:

If you want the template name, you can use:

```
{% if 'product' in _self.getTemplateName() %}
    {# Do stuff #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) let me describe what I have in mind. Imagine there is a macro located in the parent file. Inside the macro we want to check what page we are in now. If we are in a page that has `product` in its name, lets do some stuff. If current name has `article` in its name lets do some other stuff. Do you see my point?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see if this solves your problem :)

Comment: Ah seems correct. Thank you so much :) I can't give an upvote because I'm new to StackOverflow but will come back and Upvote this as soon as I reach enough points ;)